how to append two columns in the same table in Power BI
i have four columns: team1 and team2, and also goals 1, and goals2.
i want to make top 5 teams with their goals in the report view for both team1 and team2, how do i append the teams columns together and the goals column together so i can do this, or is there a better way to get the top five of the combination of both columns


Duplicate your query twice :

For the 1st duplicated table, rename team1 to Team and team1_goals to Goals and remove the team2 and team2_goals columns.


Make the same steps for the 2nd table.
Now you need to append the queries between the 2 tables :

Then group your data to sum the scores :

Sort the rows in ASC order based on the Sum of the scores :

Then keep the first 5 rows :

Final result :


I wouis not duplicate a query to accomplish this. A simple one query method would be
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Combined  = Table.RemoveFirstN(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"team1", "team1_goals"})),1)
    &Table.RemoveFirstN(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"team2", "team2_goals"})),1),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Combined, {"Column1"}, {{"Goals", each List.Sum([Column2]), type number}}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.FirstN(Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"Goals", Order.Descending}}),5)
in #"Sorted Rows"

